# How to remove outer quotes and transform it into a character vector in R

Tags: r

I have an example character (not sure what exactly format it is called) that appears as:

```
var1 <- "'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'G'"
```

I wonder how do I remove the outer double quotes and transform it into a character vector that looks exactly like:

```
var2 <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'G')
```

that can be further used in creating data frames or plots, etc.?

Comment: something like `strsplit(gsub("'| ","",var1), ",")[[1]]` perhaps? This removes the single-quotes, spaces, and then splits the single character into its components

Comment: Could also do: `stringr::str_split_1(stringr::str_remove_all(var1, "'"), ',')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You essentially have a string which is a quoted CSV. I like the functionality of `scan` for dealing with such circumstances cleanly, since you can specify separators, output class, quoting characters, and how to deal with white space all in one go:

```
var2 <- scan(text=var1, sep=",", what="", strip.white=TRUE)
#Read 8 items
var2
#[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "F" "G"
```

The output structure is exactly as you wished:

```
dput(var2)
#c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "F", "G")
```